# How to fetch content for a component on click of a button outside this component with Vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a modal which I want to the content to be updated whenever I click on a button. This button is not in the component, and I need it to update an item slug, which will be used to fetch content from API.

I'm new to Vuejs.

Here is my app.js :

```
Vue.component('pop-modal', require('./components/PopModal.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        popSlug: 0
    },
    methods: {
        updatePop: function(popSlug) {
            this.popSlug = popSlug
            console.log(this.popSlug)
        }
    }
});
```

And here is my component:

```
<template>
    <div class="modal fade" id="popModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h1>{{ pop.name }}</h1>
                <p>test: {{ this.$parent.popSlug }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                pop: {},
            }
        },
        watch: {
            popSlug(newPopslug) {
                this.popSlug = newPopslug
                this.fetchData()
                console.log('new popslug value!')
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component pop-modal mounted.')
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData() {
                axios.get(route('api.pops.show'), this.popSlug)
                .then(response => {
                  // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                  this.pop = response.data
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  this.errors.push(e)
                })
                console.log('fetchData')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I know I'm doing it wrong but I don't know how to do it right.
The watch method is never triggered because popSlug is not a data attribute.
I'm able to get popSlug value with:

```
{{ this.$parent.popSlug }}
```

But I think it's the wrong way to do this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `popSlug` value as a prop to the component as explained in the documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Composing-with-Components). Then in the `pop-modal` component, you can access the value as `this.popSlug` and the watch will react to changes. Just make sure to don't modify the prop value inside the component, because it is supposed to be a read-only value.

Here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/sebaap/cckLd9te/1390/). The `internalValue` is only used to show that the watch is being called. You can use `anyname` directly in the template.

Comment: Thanks but it seems to not working, I added prop to my component, but watch is never triggered.

Comment: I added a fiddle example. Hope it helps.